# Chrome takes 3 minutes to intially load websites / Windows 7

Tags: google-chrome

I have an older Dell OptiPlex PC, with 4GB RAM, and a 3GHz CPU.

When I open Chrome, Chrome will take about 2-4 minutes spinning its "in progress" icon to the left of the page title in the tab, before it starts to load a website, when action is seen in the status bar at the bottom of the window.

"Change Proxy settings" > "LAN Settings" > "Automatically detect settings" is unchecked.

What is causing the initial delay?

Is it checking the cache?

Comment: Is it still slow when running Chrome with the `--disable-extensions` command-line option to disable extensions?

Comment: Yes @harrymc it is.

Comment: can you post results from speedtest.net , pingtest.net and make ping google.com from cmd? According to the result I can say if it is from your internet, otherwise it can be a virus, a clean install of chrome or reinstall of pc will help for sure.

Comment: Try in safe mode with networking and any firewalls disabled. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like most such problems are reported on Windows 8.1.
If that's your case, you should wait for Google to fix the problem.

Some solutions that worked for some :

1. Reset TCP/IP: Open cmd.exe as admin, type `netsh winsock reset`.
2. Go to Chrome Settings, Advanced Settings, scroll down and uncheck
   `Use hardware acceleration when available`.
3. Go to folder `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome`, delete the folder `UserData`,
   restart Chrome, do not open session (sign in). Some Chrome settings might be lost.
4. Disable the antivirus, to check for a possible conflict.
5. Disable Sync.
6. Try running Chrome once as admin, to see if this fixes the problem.
7. Use another browser until Google fixes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Chrome is trying to use IPv6 but your ISP is not supporting it (in Firefox I've seen similar symptoms caused by this). Could you try starting Chrome with `--disable-ipv6`?

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Kristiyan. There are several things that can cause Chrome to load slow. Giving us information about what Virus and Malware prevention you have would help. If you don't have any then I would suggest things like Malwarebytes and Spybot. for a start. Most often in the case of slow internet the Browser is not always the first thing to suspect for slow speeds.

Also there are many things that can cause that.

1. ISP issues
2. Malware
3. Viruses
4. Router issues
5. Modem issues
6. etc.

Answer (score -4):

Try using a Linux distro and see if Chrome is acting like that there if it is change to Opera or Firefox Aurora they have the closest experience to Chrome sometimes Chrome doesn't agree with your PC.